# Importing existing Android project in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

I'm getting an error from Eclipse when I try importing an existing Android project.

> Android requires compiler compliance level 5.0 or 6.0. Found '1.4' instead. Please use Android Tools > Fix Project Properties.

I did fix the properties and set the compiler level to 1.6 as well. But I'm still getting the same error. Now what should I do?

Comment: Have you installed the 1.6 JDK?

Comment: for beginners: note that the Fix Project Properties is found with a right-click on the project name in Android Tools.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with the following steps. I was able to get it to work today using Eclipse Indigo

Create New Workspace -> Open SDK Manager -> Update the SDK -> restart the eclipse -> Import the project to this workspace -> right click on Project -> Android Tools -> Fix Project properties -> restart Eclipse

Comment: that does work - but it's something that's a PITA and the dev environment should "fix" itself.

Answer (score 2):

For me it boiled down to something I would consider an Eclipse or ADT bug: this problem depends on where the workspace was created!

The problem did not appear when the structure was like this: workspace\project.
The problem did appear when the structure was like this: workspace\somesubfolder\project.

Specifying project specific settings (which is what fix properties does) seems to work around that bug and is maybe a good approach anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Doing `Project` -> `Clean...` fixed it for me.

My eclipse had stopped working so I cleaned `workspace` directory and after I run eclipse when I import the project I had this problem. Other solutions suggested here didn't work.